# Trying to receive a template in a struct and use it on a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

I'm trying to create a tree class to a test, but I'm getting: "error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template class std::vector".

```
template <typename T>
struct a {
T data;
void ReceiveData(T T_data) {
    data = T_data;
}
};
struct b {
std::vector<a> b_data;//Error here
};
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] where this error is reported, and not some random chunk of code that may or may not have anything to do with this compilation error. The shown code, by itself, will have plenty of compilation errors before it even gets to the `std::vector` part. For more information, see [ask] questions.

Comment: what is `T`? Is `a` meant to be a template?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the template type of `a`:

```
template<typename T> struct a 
{
   T data;
   void ReceiveData(T T_data) 
   {
      data = T_data;
   }
};

template<typename T> struct b 
{
   std::vector<a<T>> b_data; //compiles now
   //          ^^^^
};
```

Note that `a` alone is not a type, it is a template.
Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Wqxeus)